# Why convert IP Address to Hostname by used "gethostbyaddr" but don't work?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

I try to convert IP Address to Hostname by used  "gethostbyaddr" but don't work. I use file.text that is log file to analyze which page that user used a lot or less. So I try to cut sentence that use array.  This is my code.

```
$file=fopen("log.txt","r");             

while (!feof($file)) {
    $buffer = fgets($file, 4096);                    

    $text= explode(" ",$buffer,10);



    $text_2=@$text[1];  
    $ip=substr($text_2,1,11);       
    $ip2=gethostbyaddr($ip);

    echo"INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('$ip2');"."<br>";        //Show results

    //echo"<br>";           //New line
}

fclose($file);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any error ? Your code may work.

Comment: I want to convert ip address to host such as '61.47.47.85' convert to www.hostname.com  but it's still show ip address even though  I use 'gethostbyaddr'. Thank you

Comment: Not every IP address is set up to be reverse looked-up to a hostname. Do you have an indication that it *should* work?

Comment: No, I don't have it. Could you suggest another way to get this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

that means  gethostbyaddr  failed.

not because your input, find the explanation in php documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

"Returns the host name on success, the unmodified ip_address on failure, or FALSE on malformed input."

Comment: Thanks. I think because of Not every IP address is set up to be reverse like "deceze" talk about.